# Calligraphic logo in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

Yep, it's that time again. I want to design a calligraphic logo and my obvious choice as LaTeX enthousiast is TikZ as implementation. Only, I lack the proper skills to do so and need some inspiration.

In particular, that of the "Copenhagen Suborbitals" caught my eye. How can I achieve something similar?

For reference:

[image]

Comment: This looks great. Can you show what you have done so far and exactly what you are having a problem with.

Comment: I guess I'd start by writing a package to emulate a calligraphic pen ...

Comment: Gotta love that phallus ... I concur with Peter though, this question is really unspecific and doesn't show any effort whatsoever, hence -1. A similarly effortless answer would be: _Learn TikZ._

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is a point to start

**Picture**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfornament,tikzrput}         % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/tikzrput/
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}  % altermundus.com/pages/tkz/ornament/ 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[ultra thick] circle[radius=6cm] circle[radius=7cm]  ;
\draw[line width=2mm] circle[radius=7.4cm]  ;

\path 
    [rotate=210,postaction={decoration={text along path,text format delimiters={|}{|}, text={|\Huge| AD ASTRA {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}} COPENHAGEN SUBORBITALS {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}} NON LUCROR {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}} EXPOSITA SCIENTIA {\pgfornament[scale=.4,ydelta=-9pt]{15}}},
      text align=fit to path,reverse path}, decorate}]
     circle[radius=6.2cm] ; 
      \rput{-20}(1.5,5.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2]{87}}
      \rput{20}(-1.5,5.2){\pgfornament[scale=.2]{87}} 
      \rput(0,0){\pgfornament[scale=.8]{75}}
      \rput{-90}(2,0){\pgfornament[scale=.8]{72}}
      \rput{90}(-2,0){\pgfornament[scale=.8,symmetry=v]{72}}  
  \node[font=\huge] at (0,-5){MMVIII} ;   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Some links about answers with pgfornament and tikzrput

[answer 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/)
[answer 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/package-for-certificates)
[answer 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46798/how-do-we-draw-a-bird-in-latex)

Comment: Where's pgfornament from?  I can't find it on CTAN.

Comment: It is amazing how easy this is compared to Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape once you have learned to use TikZ.

Comment: @AndrewStacey See on Altermundus website. It is his package. Altermundus: nice package.

Comment: (site seems to be down right now, I'll check it another time)

Comment: There is  problem  to upload pgfornament on CTAN because the initial symbols format ai or eps are free but with a special licence. I made these symbols with a format that I call `pgf` but I need to cite  the author. psvectorian is not on ctan too but i don't know the real reason. I finish the documentation of tikzrput and I sent it on CTAN very soon.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Actually it's fine you can access the site

Comment: I keep getting `502 Bad Gateway Nginx` when I try the site.

Comment: fine bad fine bad ... random story! Sorry but I can not do much. I think this a problem with a server of my provider.

Comment: Now I know why, from webfaction : As scheduled we are starting the migration of Web199 to new hardware. During the migration services on the machine will be unavailable. We will update this post once the migration is over.

Comment: I could not have asked for a better answer. This is perfect, thanks! Way enough to get me started.

Comment: You can look at xelatex to use other fonts. You can also use  fonts with ornaments  instead of symbols like vectorian but you can start with my example. It's also possible to add object from Inskape.

Comment: @Ingo Now you can find the package `pgfornament` on ctan