# Recreating a logo (text around a circle)

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

My objective is to figure out how to put text around the circumference of a circle as shown below.

[image]

I have read [Calligraphic logo in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47898/10898) which answer part of my question but not completely as shown in the bottom text. I have the following:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=gray,fill=MidnightBlue] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=gray,fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node {\Huge\bf MTG};
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2pt,text along path, 
text=St. John's College}}] (0,0) circle (3.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

which of course is not what I want.

Comment: Note: If you use a negative radius, the text flips.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I do agree :-)

Comment: `reverse path=true` has the same effect. ;)

Comment: Let me ask you: What is what you want? What text should appear? Where do you have your problems?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I want the text as it appears in the first diagram. The text seem to be center vertically with respect to the circle and the bottom text is upright which i suppose may be resolved with you previous comments.

Answer (score 32):

I used [`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) and XeLaTeX, but you can use, of course, any font.

Just to get you started:

### MWE

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=gray,fill=MidnightBlue] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=gray,fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node {\Huge\bfseries MTG};
\node at (0,1.2) {\large\bfseries\color{gray} founded};
\node at (0,-1.2) {\large\bfseries\color{gray}\Lonum{2012}};
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);

\path
    [
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                raise=-7pt,
                text along path,
                text align/fit to path stretching spaces=true,
                reverse path=true,
                text align/align=center,
                text align/left indent={9.5818575934488693773110623190025cm}, % \pi * radius
                text align/right indent={0.0cm},
                text={| \biolinum\scshape\Large\bfseries |MXII|\biolinum\huge\scshape| – St. John's College – |\biolinum\scshape\bfseries\Large|MXII}
            }
        }
    ]
    [
        postaction={
            decorate,
            decoration={
                raise=-5.5pt,
                text along path,
%               text align/fit to path stretching spaces=true,
%               reverse path=true,
                text align/align=center,
                text align/left indent={9.7818575934488693773110623190025cm}, % \pi * radius + .2cm
                text align/right indent={.2cm},
                text={|\biolinum \bfseries\huge | • made by Qrrbrbirlbel • }
            }
        }
    ]
(0,0) circle (3.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: MWE compiled with XeLaTeX]

---

The bun­dle, `libertineotf` is now ob­so­lete, be­ing re­placed by the `lib­er­tine` pack­age.

The MWE can be compiled by making the following adjustments:

1. Replace `\usepackage{libertineotf}` with `\usepackage{libertine}`
2. Replace `\Lonum{2012}` with `\oldstylenums{2012}`

Comment: You're missing an M: it should be MMXII :)

Comment: @F'x No Qrrbrbirlbel answered this over 1000 years ago. He was waiting for the question.

Comment: CTAN (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) informs the following with libertineotf:  The bun­dle is now ob­so­lete, be­ing re­placed by the lib­er­tine pack­age.

Answer (score 29):

Similar but slower.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{fontspec,amssymb}
\setmainfont{OptimusPrinceps}
\definecolor{byublue}{RGB}{0 34 85}
\newfontfamily\bolderfont{OptimusPrincepsSemiBold}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw[color=gray,fill=byublue] (0,0) circle (3.5cm);
\draw[color=gray,fill=white] (0,0) circle (2.6cm);
\end{scope}
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (2.5cm) node[scale=1.5] (m) {\Huge\bolderfont MTG};
\draw[color=gray] (0,0) circle (3.6cm);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, 
reverse path,text align=center,
text={|\huge\color{white}|Quick Latin Motto Erratum Et Al.}}}] (-30:3.05cm) arc (-30:210:3.05cm);
\node[white,rotate=-60] at (210:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};
\node[white,rotate=60] at (330:3.05cm) {$\blacklozenge$};
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1ex,text along path, text align=center,
text={|\huge\color{white}|St. John's College }}}] (210:3.05cm) arc (210:330:3.05cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can the two horizontal lines be added relative to the abbreviation MTG?

Comment: @azetina Yes, that is a node anyway so you can `\draw (m.north west) -- (m.north east)` or use these coordinates as guides.

Comment: @percusse can you explain why the `|   |` syntax is necessary to specify the white text color? I've wasted a fair bit of time wondering why `\color{white}` doesn't work, but rather I need `|\color{white}|`.

Comment: @Ingo Otherwise TikZ thinks that `\color{white}` is part of the decoration text which is clearly not. So it escapes to the options fixes the color and resumes parsing.

Comment: Interesting, this is the only occasion in all packages that I have ever used where this was necessary.

Comment: @Ingo This probably the only package which can decorate the paths with text you have used too :) It is not simply pasting letters, it is adjusting every letter to the path so it's not a standard paragraph text. Notice that your text is an argument to `text` key not a node text hence special care is needed.