# assistance on good handling of text on TikZ paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, rotating, paths, circles

I am putting together an ornate logo using TikZ. The logo as it is currently is as follows:

[image: example of ornate logo using TikZ]

I request assistance on handling the lowermost outer text (which reads "UNIVERSITY OF GLASGOW"). For the purposes of easy legibility, I would like the text to be inverted with respect to what it is now. I'm relatively new to TikZ and I'm not sure how to approach the problem.

Comments on improving the code generally also are welcome. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
% TikZ
    \usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text} 
% font size
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
% cryillic font
    \usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}
    \newcommand\cyr{%
        \renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
        \renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
        \renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
        \normalfont
        \selectfont
    }
    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}
    \def\Eoborotnoye{\char3}
    \def\eoborotnoye{\char11}
    \def\cprime{\char126}
    \def\cdprime{\char127}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % outer circle
            \draw[line width=2 mm] circle[radius=7.4 cm];
        % inner circles
            \draw[ultra thick] circle[radius=6 cm] circle[radius=7 cm]  ;
        % outer text
            \path[
                rotate=-15.2,
                postaction={
                    decoration={
                        text along path,
                        text format delimiters={|}{|},
                        text={
                            |\Huge|
                            {\pgfornament[scale=.4, ydelta=-9 pt]{15}}
                            UNIVERSITY OF GLASGOW
                            {\pgfornament[scale=.4, ydelta=-9 pt]{15}}
                            OFFICIAL DRINK PARTICLE PHYSICS EXPERIMENT
                        },
                        text align=fit to path,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
            circle[radius=6.2 cm];
        % top ornamentation
            \rput{-30}(2.5, 4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.4]{87}}
            \rput{30}(-2.5, 4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.4]{87}} 
        % bottom ornamentation
            \rput(0, -2.5){\pgfornament[scale=.7]{75}}
        % right ornamentation
            \rput{-90}(5, 0){\pgfornament[scale=.6]{72}}
        % left ornamentation      
            \rput{90}(-5, 0){\pgfornament[scale=.6, symmetry=v]{72}}  
        % central text
            \node[font=\fontsize{35}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 2.5){P.P.E.};
            \node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 0.5){{\cyr k v a s}};    
            \node[font=\huge] at (0, -5){MMXII};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

many thanks for your assistance

Comment: As an easy way out, you can seperate into two arcs and use two decorations (one without the reverse path)

Comment: That approach makes sense. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As percusse commented, the easiest way is to use two `arc`s, one of which is without reversing the text.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
% TikZ
    \usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text}
% font size
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
% cryillic font
    \usepackage[OT2, OT1]{fontenc}
    \newcommand\cyr{%
        \renewcommand\rmdefault{wncyr}%
        \renewcommand\sfdefault{wncyss}%
        \renewcommand\encodingdefault{OT2}%
        \normalfont
        \selectfont
    }
    \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcyr}{\cyr}
    \def\Eoborotnoye{\char3}
    \def\eoborotnoye{\char11}
    \def\cprime{\char126}
    \def\cdprime{\char127}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % outer circle
            \draw[line width=2 mm] circle[radius=7.4 cm];
        % inner circles
            \draw[ultra thick] circle[radius=6 cm] circle[radius=7 cm]  ;
        % outer text
            \path[
                %rotate=-15.2,
                postaction={
                    decoration={
                        text along path,
                        text format delimiters={|}{|},
                        text={%
                            |\Huge|                            
                            {\pgfornament[scale=.4, ydelta=-9 pt]{15}}
                            OFFICIAL DRINK PARTICLE PHYSICS EXPERIMENT
                            {\pgfornament[scale=.4, ydelta=-9 pt]{15}}
                        },
                        text align=center,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
             (-27:6.2cm) arc (-27:210:6.2cm);   
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path, text align=fit to path,text={|\Huge|UNIVERSITY OF GLASGOW}}}] (209:6.8cm) arc (209:330:6.8cm);
        % top ornamentation
            \rput{-30}(2.5, 4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.4]{87}}
            \rput{30}(-2.5, 4.2){\pgfornament[scale=.4]{87}}
        % bottom ornamentation
            \rput(0, -2.5){\pgfornament[scale=.7]{75}}
        % right ornamentation
            \rput{-90}(5, 0){\pgfornament[scale=.6]{72}}
        % left ornamentation
            \rput{90}(-5, 0){\pgfornament[scale=.6, symmetry=v]{72}}
        % central text
            \node[font=\fontsize{35}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 2.5){P.P.E.};
            \node[font=\fontsize{60}{60}\selectfont] at (0, 0.5){{\cyr k v a s}};
            \node[font=\huge] at (0, -5){MMXII};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get a customized look, one may adjust the angles in the definitions of `arc`s. Some more details can be found in [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75638/recreating-a-logo-text-around-a-circle/75652#75652).

Comment: Excellent. This is clean and sensible. I thank you very much for your assistance (as does the department!).