# How to make this as a memoir chapterstyle?

Tags: memoir, chapters

The Danish translation of Murakami's *The Wind-Up Bird Chronicle* uses the following chapter style. Is it possible to somehow recreate this as a `memoir` chapter style?

The text circle always has the same radius and always starts at the same angle on the left; then the text just distributes itself along the circle as shown. So technically, if one continued the text for too long, it would bite its own tail. Don't worry about this, though, the text is not going to become much longer than this.

The position of the text circle is independent of the width of the chapter number on the left, which will have at most two digits.

[image]

A modification of Giacomo's answer that is a bit more true to the book in terms of angle and radius. Now we just need to turn it into a chapter style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\startang{170}

\coordinate (start) at (-3,0);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=left,text={|\sffamily|Sult som smerte {\textbullet} Kumikos lange brev {\textbullet} Fuglen som profet}}}] (start) arc (\startang:{\startang-360} :4 );
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The braces around `\textbullet` are necessary; else they break TikZ.

Comment: About the bullets: I just want to insert those manually, so don't worry about making support for multiple headings. Just treat the text circle as one big heading.

Comment: As long as you can find a macro that can typeset a string along a path, then it is doable. Isn't it possible to do that using tikz?

Comment: I guess it should be; there are some other questions that reveal that circular text paths are possible in `TikZ`. To me, the problem is more related to turning it into a chapter style, with the correct way of automating everything. All my attempts so far at getting an overview of the memoir chapter style syntax have failed.

Comment: Not that I know how to make ordinary circular text in `TikZ`.http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75638/recreating-a-logo-text-around-a-circle shows that `TikZ` is capable of doing, but I don't think that solution is immediately applicable in this situation.

Comment: Then provide the code for the failure. We usually do not like "make this for me" - questions

Comment: The percusse one should be usable. Works just fine with `pdflatex` and the extra fonts removed.

Comment: "The percusse one?"

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75652/3929

Comment: @daleif, the above code works for me now.

Comment: The problem with that one is the bounding box, the size of the image is actually the full circle! (add an `\fbox` around it). My `tikz` foo is quite basic so I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: That could be a problem. But I think we may as well assume that the text will never go more than half way around the circle. So we may cut the below semicircle off.

Comment: That depends greatly on the chosen fontsize

Comment: That just means that we get a chapter style where you shouldn't put too much text. Isn't actually that different from other chapter styles.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a `memoir` chapter style

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\def\startang{170}

% title on curve
\newcommand\ToC[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % depends on the chosen font size
  \clip (-1.1em,0.05) rectangle (9,4.5);
\path [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=left,
text={#1}}}] (0,0)
arc (\startang:{\startang-360} :4cm );
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\providecommand\curvefont{}
\makechapterstyle{G}{
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\afterchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\curvefont{\large\sffamily\bfseries}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \chaptitlefont\thechapter~%
    % visual baseline
    %\rlap{\kern-2em\smash{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}}%
    \curvefont\ToC{##1}
  }
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-\baselineskip}
}
\chapterstyle{G}




\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{10}

\chapter{Sult som smerte {\textbullet} Kumikos lange brev {\textbullet} Fuglen som profet}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tak skal du have!

Comment: How do I remove all the space above? The `memoir` manual mentions setting `\beforechapskip` to zero, but nothing happened.

Comment: See the update. Note you can use `\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{showlocs}` to see where the boundaries are. Because `\beforechapskip` is added via `\vspace*` we may have to go negative or simply redefine `\chapterheadstart`. BTW: depending on what you are doing, you may need to explicitly define a style for unnumbered chapters, like the TOC.

Comment: PS: one can learn a lot by just looking in the memoir source code. I have it on speed dial in my editor.

Comment: Thank you for your help. A side question that I have been thinking about: Why do you call yourself daleif? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-4,0) [shape=point] {}; 
\node (Two) at (4,0) [shape=point] {};
\draw [hidden,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=left,text={|\sffamily|How to make this as a memoir chapterstyle?}}}] (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Maybe there are more elegant ways to solve your question. This is the most simple I have thought.

[image: Result]

Comment: That example does not compile using my TL14 and `pdflatex`

Comment: I have no problem (Miktex, Win 64bit). I add a picture, just a moment.

Comment: @daleif same here. Not to mention it doesn't set up a `memoir` chapter style, which is a main point of the question.

Comment: The chapter style is the easy part. The hard part is providing a macro that can print a string along the upper half of a circle beginning a approx 9 'o clock. When that is available the rest is a peace of cake, just define `\printchaptertitle` appropriately.

Comment: @GiacomoAlessandroni exactly which tikz versions are you using?

Comment: My pgf/tikz version is: 3.0.0

Comment: It works for me. I'm currently modifying it to suit my needs. I don't know how to check my tikz version, but I'm using TeX Live 2014 on Windows.