# Creating this logo in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

how to create this logo using TikZ

[image: how to design this logo in TiKz]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so could you provide it?

Comment: `\includegraphics`  (logos are usually trademarked entities that should be copied exactly not approximated)

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75638/recreating-a-logo-text-around-a-circle

Comment: You're probably better off importing a vector image.

Comment: Isn't this question beyond the scope of TikZ and LaTeX? :/

Answer (score 4):

If you have a vector version of this logo encapsulated in an .eps file, then you can use the [eps2pgf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eps2pgf/) tool that will transform it into a TikZ/pgf plot.
It might require a bit of cleaning though.