# Packages for the stamps by postal mail

Tags: packages

Using the same words I used for this question, I have observed, not with lot care, that there are question on TeX.SE. concerning stamps (or round stamp) by postal mail.

*Is there a specific package to add my custom "stamp" or round stamp (with text and date)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only package that came up when I was searching for this, was [postage](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/postage). This seems to only produce stamps for the "Deutsche Post AG" so it might not be what you want.

Furthermore these questions here on SO might be helpful if you are looking to creating stamps (though more image-based than text-based):

- [How to make a realistic old rubber stamp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96106/how-to-make-a-realistic-old-rubber-stamp)
- [Toward a Stamper Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96678/toward-a-stamper-package)

Other than that I don't know of any such package and wasn't able to find anything else.

Comment: In the meantime, thank you very much. But why are the stamps German? Hahahah. I'm joking. I didn't know this package at all and thank you very much again. But is a stamp where I can put a day and my title?

Comment: @Sebastiano Not that I know of. Which doesn't have to mean a lot given that I haven't needed it before. However I think you might get what you want if you're willing to dig into the implementation of that packages and adapt it to your needs :)