# A special annulment (i.e., cancellation) of a stamp

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikzlibrary

Related to this question [Packages for the stamps by postal mail](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536760/packages-for-the-stamps-by-postal-mail) I have seen that there is a LaTeX code in this [link](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/envelope/):

```
% Envelope
% Author: Émeric Tourniaire
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Contour
  \draw[fill=black!10] (2,-1.7) coordinate (a)
             rectangle (7,1.7)  coordinate (b) ;

  % Upper pane
  \draw [fill=black!10,rounded corners] (b) -- ++(120:1)
    -- ($(a|-b)+(60:1)$) -- (a|-b) ;

  % Orange decoration
  \coordinate (c) at (3,0.5) ;
  \coordinate (d) at (6,0.5) ;
  \draw [orange] ($(c)+(0,-.2)$) -- (c) -- ++(0.2,0)
                 ($(d)+(0,-.2)$) -- (d) -- ++(-0.2,0);
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}
    \draw[orange] ({3+\i*0.25},-1) rectangle ++(0.2,0.3);
  \draw[orange] (4.4,-1) -- (6,-1);

  % White lines
  \draw [white] (3,-0.5) -- (6,-0.5)
                (3,0)    --    (6,0);

  % Writing
  \draw (3,0)    node [anchor=base west] {\textsc{Name} Firstname};
  \draw (3,-0.5) node [anchor=base west] {Adress};
  \draw (4.4,-1) node [anchor=base west] {City};
  \foreach[count=\i] \zip in {1,2,3,4,5}
    \draw ({3-0.125+\i*0.25},-0.85) node {\zip};

  % Stamp
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (5,1.7) -- (7,1.7) -- (6.9,1) arc (0:360:4mm)
                  -- (7,0.5) -- (5,0.5) -- cycle ;
    \foreach \i in {-3,...,3}
      \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=0.6mm,segment length=5mm}] 
         (5.2,1+\i/10) -- (6.5,1+\i/10);
  \end{scope}
  \draw (6.5,1) circle (4mm);
        (6.5,1) circle (2.2mm);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={text along path,
    text={|\fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont| Postal stamp}}]
    (6.25,1) arc  (180:-180:2.5mm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have select only the important part for me:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Stamp
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (5,1.7) -- (7,1.7) -- (6.9,1) arc (0:360:4mm)
                  -- (7,0.5) -- (5,0.5) -- cycle ;
    \foreach \i in {-3,...,3}
      \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=0.6mm,segment length=5mm}] 
         (5.2,1+\i/10) -- (6.5,1+\i/10);
  \end{scope}
  \draw (6.5,1) circle (4mm);
        (6.5,1) circle (2.2mm);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={text along path,
    text={|\fontsize{3pt}{3pt}\selectfont| Postal stamp}}]
    (6.25,1) arc  (180:-180:2.5mm) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but using [Papeeria](https://www.papeeria.com/), for example, I have this error:

```
Missing chars   (,6,.,5,,,1,),c,i,r,c,l,e,(,2,.,2,m,m,),;
```

The output exist and it is this:

[image]

Is it possibile to adapt this last code to have a circle with this structure? I am not able to make it. Thank you vey much for your help.

[image]

Comment: I edited your title to include the American English term of "cancellation", to augment your term "annulment".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Very kind Steven, I have used the translator :-( sigh sigh. Thank you very much for your edit.

Comment: It my very well be "annulment" in different English-speaking cultures, I do not know.  I just know that in the US, the post office "cancels" stamps to indicate usage.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you very much for your cooperation and interest in my application. Thank you again and good work. I always wish you the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted but here's an example of the second one using the first one's template. I had to change the measurements and simplify the code because it was too small to contain all of that text in a circle.

Note also that the wavy lines actually often appear *on top* of the stamp, if you look at examples of stamps online.

### Output

<sub>**Stamp in detail**</sub>
[image: stamp in detail]

<sub>**Example on envelope**</sub>
[image: example on envelope]

### Code

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[left=.5in,top=0.15in,papersize={4.125in,9.5in},landscape,twoside=false]{geometry} % envelope size
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for the \bigstar
\usepackage[datesep={.},style=dmyyyy]{datetime2} % for the date format

\setlength\parskip{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.text}


\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift={(current page.north east)}, xshift=-3cm, yshift=-2.5cm]
    \begin{scope}      
        \foreach \i in {-4,...,3}{
            \draw[decorate,decoration={snake,amplitude=2mm,segment length=1.2cm}] 
                (-4.5,.4+\i/4) -- (-1,.4+\i/4);
        }
            \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (1.6cm);
        \pgfmathsetmacro\rightind{pi*1.5}    
            \path[%
                postaction={decorate,
                decoration={%
                text along path,
                reverse path,
                raise=-3pt,
                text align=center,
                text align={fit to path stretching spaces},
                text={|\scshape\fontsize{6}{4}\selectfont\sffamily|Leonardo da vinci - v centenario della scomparsa}
                }}] (-15:1.5cm) arc (-15:195:1.5cm);
            \node[font=\fontsize{6}{4}\selectfont] at (200:1.45cm) {$\bigstar$};
            \node[font=\fontsize{6}{4}\selectfont] at (-20:1.45cm) {$\bigstar$};
            \path[%
                postaction={decorate,
                decoration={%
                text along path,
                raise=-.5pt,
                text align={fit to path stretching spaces},
                text={|\scshape\sffamily\fontsize{6}{4}\selectfont|10121 Spazio Filatelia Torino}
            }}] (205:1.5cm) arc (205:335:1.5cm);
            %;
            %
            \path[%
                postaction={decorate,
                decoration={%
                text along path,
                text align=center,
                text={|\scshape\sffamily\fontsize{6}{4}\selectfont|\today}
            }}] (180:1.2cm) arc (180:360:1.2cm);
            \node[circle, draw, thick, font=\scriptsize\sffamily\bfseries, inner sep=1pt] at (225:1cm) {PT}; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}%
FROM-NAME

FROM-STREET ADDRESS

FROM-CITY, STATE, \ ZIP

\vspace{1.5in}\large
\setlength\parindent{3.5in}

TO-NAME

TO-STREET ADDRESS

TO-CITY, STATE, \ ZIP
\end{document}
```

Comment: I thank you and all the users for the attention you have towards me. You have been very good at making the stamp. I asked for help because I am not able to modify the original code. With your code I can make some changes, but with all sincerity I was only interested in the postmark. When my students send pdfs of their homework due to the Covid-19 problem I have to avoid as much as possible to touch many of the students' notebooks. With pdfescape an online tool I can add the stamp as an image. Thank you very much for your personal help. With esteem. Sebastiano. +1

Comment: @Sebastiano the envelope is just for context, like an extra :)

Comment: Ah :-)....then..again a double thank you very much also again.