# Simulate printing imperfections and defects with TeX?

Tags: fonts, printing, fun

Is there a way to simulate imperfections of some of the older books in LaTeX? Like the missing pieces of letters, extra splotches of ink and such?

Here is an interesting artifact:
[image]

P.S.: I guess one way would be to get an old printer haha :-0

Comment: I think this links would be useful: [Are there other “fun” packages like the “coffee stains” package?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67656/are-there-other-fun-packages-like-the-coffee-stains-package), [What is the most bizarre thing you have seen done with TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104248/what-is-the-most-bizarre-thing-you-have-seen-done-with-tex/).

Comment: Count Zero - wherever there is fun to be had, I'll be there!

Comment: There are also fonts that have a splotchy, worn look to them, though I can't give pointers off the top of my head.  In addition, there are a number of "antique" fonts, of yesteryear.

Comment: The (free) [IM Fell fonts](http://www.dafont.com/im-fell-types.font) include some of this “antique“ looking fonts …

Comment: Quite remarkable, the human nature: at first we pursue perfection and when we achieve something along those lines, we suddenly desire vintage and controlled imperfection. We can find the same trend in clothing, design, art in general. It would be interesting to see major journals switch to monospaced fonts. `:-)`

Comment: Related: [What's a good typewriter template?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/whats-a-good-typewriter-template)

Comment: Antique fonts really don't cut it. Want random imperfections.
I suspect the answer is to randomly put splotches of white over the top using TIKZ. But I know nothing of this.

Comment: there's the rather amusing stuff on ctan at fonts/ransom.  i guess the font itself only ever appeared as the 300dpi gf&pk fonts, but that would obviously have a retro (not to say retarded) effect.  the other one of don's merry japes started as don's metafont `punk` fonts.  the metafont fonts were generated with some variable (random) parameters; the `punknova` otf fonts have several different shapes for each glyph, and the shape used is selected at random, as typesetting proceeds.

Answer (score 32):

Well, I finally got a chance to look over my font library for fonts that might fit your description as "defective" and "old".  This may not be exactly what you are looking for, because these are particular fonts, rather than defects in a font which you, the user, specify.   Nonetheless, here they are.

The best example of general use has got to be [Dominican](http://haroldsfonts.com/portfolio/dominican/), one of my favorite fonts:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Another is Butterbrotpapier, notice the descended "b" for example:

[image]

Similar aged fonts exist for blackletter:

[image]
[image]

There are also fonts that exhibit defect, but are specialized, and probably not of general use, such as these:

[image]
[image]

I also have a number of older fonts that are not defective in their construction, but are from a bygone era.  I'll post only one here, as a good example...Caslon Antique.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a CV of an ancient pirate judging from the names :)

Comment: Are those fonts freely available?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  It's been a decade.  Not sure where to get them anymore.  I'd suggest Google as a start.

Comment: http://www.dafont.com/butterbrotpapier.font http://www.dafont.com/worn-manuscript-rou.font http://www.dafont.com/gf-gesetz.font http://www.dafont.com/ringbearer.font http://fontzone.net/font-details/buccaneer http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/caslon-antique (Just the first results from Google that looks right; as with anything on the internet, use your smarts.  FWIW, I'd trust all of these.  I've also edited in what *appears* to be an official distribution point for *Dominican*.)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Sure as heck beats [what I'm supposed to be doing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48152/) ;-)

Comment: Oops, I forgot to ping @GonzaloMedina with the links.

Comment: Does any of them provide allographs?

Comment: @Andrestand By allographs, I am guessing you are referring to ligatures. I am not aware that they support ligatures, though some of the blackletter fonts have alternate letter support, the German tall "s" for example, used in midword.

Comment: I refer to different versions of a same glyph. In a true old book, each 'M' is different.

Comment: @Andrestand I have seen a few fonts that provide a few alternate versions (more scripty) of several capital letters, but I have not seen that available in a systematic way.

Answer (score 32):

This answer is to the question of how to dirty up an existing font, rather than using a pre-aged font.  First, you need to get a few good inkblots such as

[image]

and

[image]

Then, you need code that underlays these blots below the text, while varying which blot to underlay, how large to draw the blot, and where relative to the letter to spill the ink.  The coding is such to make sure the blot doesn't screw up the letter kerning (via `stackengine`'s `\useanchorwidth` setting [next to last argument]).

In this revision, I have also added `\wblot`, which overlays the letters with white stuff.  But in this case, I can't overlay a white graphic, because the border is rectangular, and so the overlay would also be rectangular.  Instead, I overwrite a white glyph over the desired letter.  As with the black blot, you pick the overlay glyph (instead of the black blot), the scale of the overlay blot, and the (x,y) placement of the overlay blot.

So we have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\newlength\dellet
% blot-file, blot-scale, dx, dy, character
\newcommand\blot[5]{%
  \setlength\dellet{\widthof{#5}}%
  \stackengine{#4\dellet}{\phantom{#5}}%
    {\hspace{#3\dellet}\includegraphics[scale=#2]{#1}}%
    {O}{l}{T}{T}{L}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\usebox{\stackedbox}}{#5}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}
\newcommand\wblot[5]{%
  \setlength\dellet{\widthof{#5}}%
  \stackengine{#4\dellet}{\phantom{#5}}%
    {\hspace{#3\dellet}\textcolor{white}{\scalebox{#2}{#1}}}%
    {O}{l}{T}{T}{L}%
  \stackengine{0pt}{#5}{\usebox{\stackedbox}}{O}{l}{F}{T}{L}%
}
\begin{document}
\blot{blot1}{.0025}{.1}{.1}{H}%
\blot{blot1}{.0045}{.4}{.4}{o}%
\blot{blot2}{.0025}{.7}{.6}{w}%
\ %
\blot{blot1}{.0015}{.3}{.1}{i}%
\blot{blot2}{.0035}{.5}{.2}{s}%
\ %
\blot{blot2}{.003}{.2}{.5}{t}%
\blot{blot2}{.002}{.1}{.1}{h}%
\blot{blot1}{.004}{.2}{.3}{i}%
\blot{blot2}{.004}{.5}{.4}{s}%
\blot{blot1}{.006}{.7}{.8}{?}%

\wblot{$\wedge$}{.50}{.2}{.1}{H}%
\wblot{/}{1.0}{.4}{.4}{o}%
\wblot{*}{.70}{.6}{.0}{w}%
\ %
\wblot{y}{.90}{.3}{.1}{i}%
\wblot{z}{1.2}{.5}{.2}{s}%
\ %
\wblot{q}{.90}{.2}{.5}{t}%
\wblot{A}{.70}{.1}{.1}{h}%
\wblot{t}{.65}{.3}{.3}{i}%
\wblot{n}{.80}{.5}{.4}{s}%
\wblot{o}{.90}{.7}{.8}{?}%
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

The top line shows black blots underlaid, while the bottom line shows white overlays added.

Obviously, the shape and library of blots is a key parameter, and mine is limited to two, for example purposes only.  I imagine ones would look better if they didn't look like spills, but rather stray imprints.  Further, one doesn't want to throw them around gratuitously as I did in the MWE.

I will leave it to others to figure out how to randomly throw these about a document, rather than explicitly lay them in, as I have.

Comment: so, did anybody figure out how to add these randomly?

Comment: @Masum No one has spoken up about it...however, you may also check the "Linked Questions" that appear in the right-hand column, in case someone did so with a link to this question/answer.