# How to make my text more tasty?

Tags: fonts, fun

> **This is one of my favorite problems. Enjoy!**

We'd like to make holes in the text to make it look more tasty, like cheese tasty. We can find several fonts for this purpose, but we cannot (pseudo-randomly) change the location of the holes. That's pity! Could it be done in TeX to get something like this (the change of the background color should be a proof that there are holes not only circles drawn with the same color as the initial background color)? I enclose a close-up and some variants.

[image: mwe, close-up]

[image: mwe]

> **Update**

We cannot use the background color, if there is any, for circles: we would face a problem of shaded and other type of backgrounds. I enclose an example.

[image: mwe with different background]

> **Minimal working example**

If we need some minimal working example (let's call it a static solution), this is it using two fonts available from Dafont.com, [Cheese and Mouse font](http://www.dafont.com/cheese-and-mouse.font) and [JI Swiss Cheese font](http://www.dafont.com/ji-swiss-cheese.font). After downloading the ZIP files, unzipping them, deleting spaces in filenames and installing them we can use them (`xelatex` and `lualatex` engines can be used):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont{JISwissCheese.ttf}
JI Swiss Cheese\par
\setmainfont{CheeseandMouse.ttf}
Cheese and Mouse
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe via two fonts]

> **A tip if you got stuck**

Back in 2011, I've found this Q+A, it helped me a lot to solve this particular task for TeX hobbyists, [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz)
As long as I remember it was one of the first TeX.SX websites I visited.

Comment: You definitely have too much time :-) Looks funny and good!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex/123102#123102

Comment: Additionally, I hope, nobody changes the title of the 'question' to `How to make my text more nasty` ...

Comment: Is it a real question then?

Comment: @ienissei It depends, I've got a solution which worked for me. But any solution can be improved somehow. So it isn't a question, but I've tried to submit a (tasty) problem for other TeX hobbyists.

Comment: Why not simply draw circles with the same color as the background color over the fonts? That is trivial to do in Context, and, I believe, easy to do in LaTeX with eso-pic + tikz.

Comment: @Aditya I will submit an update: because it wouldn't work with shaded background.

Comment: @Malipivo In that case, could you please reformulate your question by not stating that it is solved (easy, right?), by shaping it into a question, and by showing your solution in your answer as you started doing? It is perfectly fine to answer your own question. That way it would look like a real question and others would feel like contributing.

Comment: @ienissei Of course, it's done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've tried to submit a gift/surprise question to my fellow solvers and I've originally marked it as solved because I know that feeling trying to solve some difficult question when I suddently discover that it has already been solved. But I didn't want to spoil the fun by submitting an anwer right away.

I enclose my original solution from 2011 with some updates. I've never used it in real typography, it was just an example for the audience (non-TeXists) of what TeX could handle. This Q+A at TeX.SX helped me a lot back then, [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz)

```
% run: any latex engine; mal-cheese.tex
\def\maltext{My tasty example}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}
%\setmainfont{[csb10]} % My original font for xelatex...
\bfseries
\fontsize{40}{72}
\def\empty{}

% This has been my original setting which requires two runs of TeX...
\ifx\relax
\tikzstyle{reverseclip}=[insert path={
  (current page.north east) --
  (current page.south east) --
  (current page.south west) --
  (current page.north west) --
  (current page.north east)}]
\fi
% This is a new approach which requires only one run of TeX...
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={clip, insert path={{[reset cm] (-16383.99999pt,-16383.99999pt) rectangle (16383.99999pt,16383.99999pt)
    }}}}

\def\typesetme#1{%
\newpage
\if#1\empty\else%\pagecolor{#1} % My original setting...
\fi
%\def\vlastniobjekt{% a new command
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[remember picture, overlay,
  [m/.style={clip,rounded corners}, outer sep=0pt]
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox} 
\shade[left color=#1, right color=yellow] (-70mm,-2cm) rectangle (7cm,4cm);
\node[yshift=10mm, %fill=#1, % right color=yellow, 
minimum height=4cm] at (0mm,0) {\raisebox{6mm}[0pt][0pt]{\maltext}}; % \muj
\pgfmathsetseed{101}%100
\foreach \a in {1,...,600}{
\pgfmathrandominteger{\x}{-62}{62}
\pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{-6}{7}
\path (\x mm,\y mm) circle (0.9mm) [reverseclip];
%\draw (\x mm,\y mm) circle (.8mm);
}
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\node at (0mm,0) {\maltext}; %\muj
\end{tikzpicture}}% konec \hbox...
%}% end of new command
%\vlastniobjekt % activating a new command...
\copy0%
}% End of \typesetme...

\ifx\relax
% This has been my original example to the audience...
%\typesetme{} % white
\foreach \barva in {0,10,...,100} {
  \typesetme{yellow!\barva}
  } % intensity of yellow
\foreach \barva in {100,90,...,0} {
  \typesetme{green!\barva}
  } % intensity of green
\fi

% An example for TeX.SX...
\typesetme{red}
\typesetme{blue}
\typesetme{green}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]