# Random imperfections simulating traditional print

Tags: typography, random

Is there an easy way to accomplish something like this:

[image]

I am aware this is scanned, what I want is the random ink distribution and character placement.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex?lq=1