# Old books appearance and font

Tags: fonts, books

As opposed to a clean and crisp *font and look* that results from a normal TeX `.pdf` export, I wish to get the following overall look and feel in my documents, mimicking Cambridge *John Wilson and Son* print or similar. I am explicitly looking for same font and global layout of the document. (Big title in caps and smallcaps for the chapter name underneath "CHAPTER N.xx".

[image]

I understand that the imperfections on the font may come as a result of actual mechanical printer ink spreading into the paper or similar phenomenona. I've tried asking here before and reducing the overall size of the .pdf document in hopes of achieving this via compression, to no avail.

Comment: Related/duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122970/simulate-printing-imperfections-and-defects-with-tex

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/whats-a-good-typewriter-template

Comment: Personally I wouldn't go there. But if I wanted to, I would probably convert the PDF to bitmaps and then use some GIMP script to introduce some fuzz, random noise and shades.

Comment: It is not related to the first due to the fact that I do not explicitly want the random imperfections, nor to the second, in which a typewriter font has almost no relation to what I'm asking. I want the font itself and the overall effect, will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387213/

Comment: @Thérèse many thanks! Now I only need the font and layout

Comment: I’d suggest Old Standard, but I’m not a mathematician and don’t know how much math that typeface supports.

Comment: @Vyraj I not suggested the above link because the typewriter font, but for the methods to obtain font imperfections (blur, microtype effects...) in *any font*. For choose a similar font, indeed the first place to go is the [TeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: You seem to be asking two unrelated uestions. (1) What is the font? (2) How do I do the layout? Foir the first follow Fran's comment. For the second show us an MWE of what you have tried to reproduce the layout, never mind the font you use.

Comment: I just want to say. I came here looking for the exact same thing and had my copy of "Elementary Principles of Statistical Mechanics" opened to this exact page to try and describe what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 4):

It's really late but I think this will give you a pretty close output in terms of the old appearance. You would have to add the header/footer or other customization yourself.

[How to generate old antique style books in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634784/how-to-generate-old-antique-style-books-in-latex)