# How to generate old antique style books in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

Over the past couple of years, I have been trying to create books that look like antique books using LaTeX. I have never found any proper solution until recently. And I created a class out of it. The output satisfied me very much. Here are some of the questions regarding this but none of the answers satisfied me in particular. All of them had something lacking.

[Old books appearance and font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398522/old-books-appearance-and-font)

[Old-style/Antique typesetting in LaTeX/TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/old-style-antique-typesetting-in-latex-tex)

If you check my profile, you will see I have also asked a lot of questions regarding this. And every time I got answers that seemed to tailored for a particular need. So, the question is, how can we produce antique style books in LaTeX? Here are some examples.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit: There may be further updates but I cannot change the class here every time. So I suggest you go to the github link attached and get the latest version.

Latest update: I was able to generate output which is fairly similar to the books by Landau, Bachmann or the paper by Riemann.

[image]

In my solution, while it is not possible to produce the exact roughness and the irregularity of old printing, the output can be pretty close. This solution works for XeLaTeX only, although it should not generate any errors for pdflatex.

I have created a class based on the typical book class which is in the repo here. It has both the class and an example of how to use it so you can see what the output looks like.

https://github.com/proafxin/antique_book

[image]