# XeLaTeX how to produce roughness or irregularities of old printing?

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I have been pretty successful in copying the antique style of old books which I described here: [How to generate old antique style books in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634784/how-to-generate-old-antique-style-books-in-latex)
However, one thing is still missing. The roughness or irregularity or randomness in the font that were common in old prints cannot be reproduced in modern Latex by default. There was a post regarding this but I cannot find it anymore.

Anybody knows any package that can do this?

Comment: I have a vague feeling that DEK, or maybe someone else, created a font where the characters had slightly different forms and dimensions, thus giving a rough appearance to the output. But, I can't find any reference to this. Perhaps someone else will have a better memory.

Comment: I am pretty sure I saw a post regarding this issue. But couldn't find anyting related at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using GIMP. Learn the basics of GIMP so you can apply different effects on an image. Import your pdf in GIMP on a higher resolution (I use 400+ in pixels value and my monitor is 4k, play with this one). Also, place the following script in the plugins directory, for windows, this is located in `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\plug-ins`

```
from gimpfu import *

# 1012982852
# 2826674371

def antiquify(image, rndm_pct, rndm_rcount, randomize, seed, horizontal, vertical, low_threshold, high_threshold, spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y, filename='D:/Projects/integer-seqs/output.pdf'):
    pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_start(image)
    for subimage in gimp.image_list():
        pdb.gimp_message('Antiquifying '+str(subimage.ID))
        opacity = 80
        pdb.gimp_context_set_opacity(opacity)
        drawable = subimage.active_layer
        pdb.plug_in_randomize_pick(image,drawable,rndm_pct, rndm_rcount, randomize, seed)
        pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        # pdb.plug_in_spread(subimage,drawable,spread_amount_x, spread_amount_y)
        pdb.plug_in_gauss_rle2(subimage,drawable,horizontal, vertical)
        opacity = 97.2
        pdb.gimp_context_set_opacity(opacity)
        pdb.gimp_threshold(drawable, low_threshold, high_threshold)
    pdb.gimp_undo_push_group_end(image)
    pdb.gimp_message('All processing done. Creating pdf')
    images = gimp.image_list()
    # num_images, image_ids = pdb.gimp_image_list()
    num_images = len(images)
    image_ids = [subimage.ID for subimage in images]
    pdb.file_pdf_save_multi(num_images, image_ids, False, False, False, filename, filename)
    pdb.gimp_message('Pdf created at '+filename)
    

register(
    "python-fu-antiquify",
    "Make a LaTeX document antique",
    "",
    "Masum Billal",
    "Masum Billal",
    "2022",
    "Antiquify",
    "",
    [
        # basic parameters are: (UI_ELEMENT, "variable", "label", Default)
        (PF_IMAGE, "image", "takes current image", None),
        (PF_SLIDER, "rndm_pct", "Random Percent for Pick", 10, (0, 100, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "rndm_rcount", "Number of Iteration for Pick", 1, (0, 10, 1)),
        (PF_BOOL, "randomize", "Randomize or not for Pick", True),
        (PF_INT, "seed", "Seed of randomization for Pick", 1),
        (PF_SLIDER, "horizontal", "Horizontal for Gaussian blur", .5, (0, 10, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "vertical", "Vertical for Gaussian blur", .5, (0, 10, .5)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "low_threshold", "Threshold low", 200, (0, 255, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "high_threshold", "Threshold high", 255, (0, 255, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "spread_amount_x", "Horizontal spread", 2, (0, 20, 1)),
        (PF_SLIDER, "spread_amount_y", "Vertical spread", 2, (0, 20, 1)),
        (PF_STRING, "filename", "PDF Filename", None),
    ],
    [],
    antiquify,
    menu="<Image>/Filters/Noise",
)

main()
```

Obviously, you can play around with the values and add/remove effects. Do that and get the desired amount of antiquity you want. Here is an example output.

[image: output]

Comment: Hi! I really like this plug-in, and it is almost exactly what I'm looking for for a themed document I'm making. One issue - if you import a multipage pdf in GIMP, each page is by default, opened in multiple layers. Unfortunately, I'm trying to run this on a many-page PDF. Do you have a good idea how this plug-in could be extended so that it runs this process on all layers, and then exports them all as a single PDF? Thank you!

Comment: Whoops, I guess I should have messed with image settings before asking. For anyone else using this for multiple page pdfs: import pdf in reverse order as IMAGES, not as LAYERS. It will do everything flawlessly. Thank you Masum!