Add noise to Font Glyphs and specify Multiple Appearance for same character sequence
I want to render pdf just like the old presses used to do in past. The impression differs from document to document due to varying force applied to the dye.
Suppose we try to apply the same effect in a pdf. Meaning the edges of the glyph will receive a random noise which will be seeded in the preamble of the document by LaTeX and while writing the characters will be morphed accordingly.
Can we define something in LaTeX? I think such an effect could be realised using tikz but I don't want to write documents using tikz.

Now to the second part of the question: \phi and \varphi produce different appearances for phi. My question is how can we define app1, app2, ... for a given character (or character sequence) in TeX.
If you think this question is related to the development of fonts please provide some hints about how to achieve it (although modifying a font file is not exactly what I am interested in at least for the first part).

"\phi and \varphi produce different appearances for phi." they are not implemented as different appearances for the same character, they are just different characters. There is no connection between them in the font, just latex has defined macros with similar names.

Related/Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637590/128462

Please note the one question per question rule. The Q & A format doesn't work well when you include multiple questions in a single question.

See also How to simulate old typewriter? which is now marked as a duplicate of Use LaTeX to simulate old typewriter written texts.  My answer to the former contains some tricks that would adapt well here and only requires LaTeX, not Lua

And of course How do I make my document look like it was written by a Cthulhu-worshipping madman? (and not just for the title)



Needs luatex
\documentclass{article}



\providecommand\ttbasefont{texgyreTermes-regular.otf}
\providecommand\ttoverprintnormal{0}% don't over-print
\providecommand\ttrotatenormal{2} % don't rotate so much
\providecommand\ttgreynormala{.5} % increase greylevel variablity

\usepackage{typewriter}

\begin{document}

I am willing to render pdf just like the old presses used to do in
past. The impression differs from document to document due to varying
force applied to the dye.

Suppose we try to apply the same effect in a pdf. Meaning the edges of
the glyph will recieve a random noise which will be seeded inthe
preamble of the document by LaTeX and while writing the characters
will be morphed accordingly.

Can we define something in LaTeX?
\end{document}


Hmm, this retains the glyph shape though. I guess OP wants that the glyph borders get somewhat roughened.

Interesting. Why is the space in effect in apparently lost?

@cfr I don't think it is, the ine is quite tight so the space is small and especially in the first run, the random variation made it smaller still

@ApoorvPotnis people don't always get what they ask for:-)

@DavidCarlisle In terms of positioning the glyphs, it is just to the point. As ApoorvPotnis pointed out cannot we impose distortion of shape like this? The solution linked here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/637590/128462) uses GIMP but is it not solvable through Lua engine?

@DebanjanDutta https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161920/128462
