# Reproducing old math font

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Is there by chance a math font resembling the sample equations in these trimmed images?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591148/an-exquisite-mathematical-font and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634784/how-to-generate-old-antique-style-books-in-latex,

Comment: Not completely sure but some letters seem to match Old Standard https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/oldstandard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to provide a decent emulation. You can possibly do better for the integral symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mlmodern}
\usepackage[nolimits]{cmupint}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding=\encodingdefault,family=\familydefault}

\DeclareSymbolFont{slanted}{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{sl}
\DeclareMathSymbol{g}{\mathalpha}{slanted}{`g}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cmupint}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cmupint}{m}{n}{ <-> s*[0.8] cmupint}{}


\begin{document}

$g_n$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the expansion of
\[
\frac{x^{n+1}}{\{y_1(x+a)\}^2}\exp\Bigl[-\int_0^x up(u)\,du\Bigr].
\]
It may happen that $g_n=0$ in which case $y_2(x)$ denotes
a logarithmic term.

\textbf{The Point at Infinity.}\quad In many problems

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into it.  Me and my partner are trying to restore an old book by Ian Sneddon in LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

My Old version

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setallmainfonts{Old Standard}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathptmxlargesymbols}{OMX}{ztmcm}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsumop}{\mathop}{mathptmxlargesymbols}{"50}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upprodop}{\mathop}{mathptmxlargesymbols}{"51}
\begin{document}
, for there coordinates, Laplace's equation in the form
\[\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial \rho^2} +\frac{1}{\varrho}\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial\varrho}+\frac{1}{\varrho^2}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial\phi^2}+\frac{\partial^2\psi }{\partial z^2}=0.\]

\end{document}
```