# Package for creating seal impressions?

Tags: packages

I have an official letter and I thought about a nice seal impression.

So my question is, if there is a package in latex with which I can create a nice fancy seal impression?

So somehow a old-school cool looking seal impression at the end of the letter with my signature.

Comment: A seal is either pressed into paper or added with a drop of wax? How do you think this could be done with LaTeX? Or do you want have a carbon copy of it?

Comment: I thought that a packe is somehow creating an image and putting it on the pdf. I remeber a thread where someone created this with a coffe cup impression. This is a bit nerdy, but he did a package where you could add a coffe cup impression on your paper to make it look used. In this way, but a bit more senseful with a seal.

Comment: here :http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349

Comment: I find the photographs of the cats also impressive ;-) Well, you want some kind of a stamp rather than seal, don't you?

Comment: Related: [How to make a realistic old rubber stamp?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96106/5764)

Comment: I honestly thought I'd find some request with a sound file embedded in it making seal sounds. I'm disappointed. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a package.  But if you are willing to live under the constraint that the image cannot cover the surrounding text, much can be done with a simple `\includegraphics`.  One must find signet images with a pure white background, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
Dear sir,

\lipsum[1-2]

Failure to take action will result in forfeiture of your property.

\bigskip\hspace{1.5in}Sincerely,\smallskip

\hspace{1.5in}\def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[0pt]{%
\Longstack{Joe Schmoe\\Dept of Collections\\Washington D.C.}}
  {\includegraphics{signet1}}
\end{document}
```

[image]