# Draw reversed path in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths

Is there a way to draw a TikZ path reversed?

I am trying to create some code that generates tessellating figures (to be used in [How do we Draw a Bird in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46798/how-do-we-draw-a-bird-in-latex)).

Here is what I got:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\x{2}
\def\y{4}
\def\mypath{(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (\x,0) -- (\x,\y)}
\draw \mypath;
\draw[shift={(\x,\y)}, rotate=180, blue] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It generates this:
[image: wrong]
But what I wanted is this:[image: ok]. So it is obviously not correct to rotate the path. I need to break it into two an draw it reversed.

Comment: If you just put the URL of a question in your post, it'll be converted to the question title automatically, as can be seen in my edit.

Comment: The shape is already defined in the shape library with the name `signal`. Check the manual page 439.

Comment: @percusse: I am trying to generate tessellating figures. I do not want to draw this specific shape.

Comment: I don't see how "drawing it reversed" (whatever that actually means) gives you the result you want. You seem to want to get a path that is reflected in x everywhere, and reflected in y half of the time. Perhaps you should draw a different part of the path and reflect that (since you want the reflection over the x axis everywhere, I suggest drawing either the left or right hand side and mirroring that). Perhaps I am just misunderstanding you, it's not terribly clear.

Comment: Yes, but they are not symmetric (a slight smell of group theory, yuck!). In other words they don't fit together to form a shape that you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible with the definition of `\mypath`

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\x{2}
  \def\y{4}
  \def\mypath{(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (\x,0) -- (\x,\y)}
  \draw[red] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\x{2}
  \def\y{4}
  \def\mypath{(0,0) -- (1,1) -- (\x,0) -- (\x,\y)}
  \draw[rotate=180, blue] \mypath;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There is no shift possible to complete correctly your shape

but with

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\x{2}
  \def\y{4}
  \def\mypath{((1,1) -- (\x,0) -- (\x,\y)--++(-1,1)}
  \draw[red] \mypath;
  \draw[blue,x=-0.5*\x cm,xshift=\x cm]  \mypath; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A solution to what you are trying to attempt is as follows :

1. draw path forward
2. shift
3. draw path backwards
4. close path

To make this easier, don't specify the path by actual points, but rather by displacements. The code is

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (start) at (0,0);
\def\shape{{(1,1)},{(1,-1)}}
\coordinate (shift) at (0,4);

\foreach \point [count=\n] in \shape {
        \node[coordinate] (d-\n) at \point {};
        }
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\size}{\n}

\draw (start) 
      \foreach \i in {1,...,\size} {-- ++(d-\i)} %draw forward
      -- ++(shift) %shift
      \foreach \i in {\size,...,1} {-- ++($-1*(d-\i)$)} % draw backward
      -- cycle; %close


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]