# Fix image in pst-fractal

Tags: pstricks

I have worked only in tikz, I want to make an image of 600 px by 300 px so that the edge of the fractal image is a little white blurred and the background of the box has the same color as the attached image.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fractal}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(-20,-6)(4,6)
\psframe*[linecolor=cyan](-4,-4)(4,4)
\psSier[unit=0.25,n=4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,linecolor=blue]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It can be said that the images are different.

Comment: I'd also like to draw your attention [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61623/121799) since you are saying you are more familiar with Ti*k*Z. I am wondering if one of these examples is more accessible to you.

Comment: @marmot very beautiful designs, I will keep them in mind. But in this case the fractals that present the documentation of "pst-fractal" are the ones I need for my purpose.

Comment: It is a confusing question!

Comment: Do you want the Sierpinski curve or the Julia set?

Comment: @Herbert Thank you, your answer is what I was looking for, but I would also like Julia's set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this??

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-fractal}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-10pt,-10pt)(610pt,310pt)
\psframe*[linecolor=cyan](600pt,300pt)
\rput(450pt,150pt){\psSier[unit=0.3,n=4,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,linecolor=blue]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]