# Creating rotational tiling in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am looking for help creating the attached image in Tikz. The exact coloration of the shapes and borders can be changed, but any help with creating this shape would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Related: [Penrose tiling in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61437/5764)

Comment: My answer at the link that @Werner points to includes a link to a package on CTAN that has the capability to define tiles with matching rules. This looks like an equilateral triangle with specific matching rules which, in my package, would be something like `a A 1` (so `a` matches with `A`, and `1` with itself). I'm not sure how easy the documentation is to follow, but that's where I'd start.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll try to figure out how to modify your Penrose tiling code (though, as a Tikz newby, I think it will be too much for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: tiling]

Each elementary figure is created through the `pic` element `bird`; it is based on an equilateral triangle as @Andrew Stacey explained.  Then, there are two more `pic` elements: `flock` composed of six *birds* and `flocks` composed of seven *flocks*.  The drawing consists of seven `flocks`.

The constants are there to define the points forming a bird, in the trigonometric order.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=1cm, 11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  real \r, \a1, \d1, \a2, \d2, \a3, \d3, \a4, \d4, \b, \e;
  \r = 1; \b = 5; \e = .75*\r;
  \a1 = 40; \a2 = 15; \a3 = 17; \a4 = \a1;
  \d1 = .4*\r; \d2 = .37*\r; \d3 = .65*\r; \d4 = \d3;
}
\tikzset{
  pics/bird/.style 2 args={% color, fill color
    code={%
      \draw[#1, fill=#2!20]
      (0, 0) -- +(-\a1: \d1) -- +(-\a2: \d2)
      -- +(-\a3: \d3) -- +(-\a4: \d4) -- +(-30: \r)
      {[rounded corners=2pt] -- +(\b: \e) -- +($(0: 1.732*\r) -(\b: \e)$)}
      -- +(60 -30: \r) -- +(60 -\a4: \d4) -- +(60 -\a3: \d3)
      -- +(60 -\a2: \d2) -- +(60 -\a1: \d1)  -- cycle;
    }
  },
  pics/flock/.style 2 args={% color, fill color
    code={%
      \foreach \i in {0, 2, 4}{%
        \path (0, 0) pic[rotate={60*\i}] {bird={#1}{#1}};
        \path (0, 0) pic[rotate={60*(\i +1)}] {bird={#1}{#2}};
      }
    }
  },
  pics/flocks/.style 2 args={% color, fill color
    code={%
      \path (0, 0) pic {flock={#1}{#2}};
      \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 5}{%        
          \path (\i*60: 1.732*\r) pic {flock={#1}{#2}};
      }
    }
  }  
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) pic {flocks={violet}{white}};
  \foreach \i in {0, 2, 4}{%        
    \path[rotate={\i*60}] ($(0: 1.732*\r) +(30: 3*\r)$) pic {flocks={red}{white}};
  }
  \foreach \i in {1, 3, 5}{%        
    \path[rotate={\i*60}]
    ($(0: 1.732*\r) +(30: 3*\r)$) pic {flocks={green!50!blue}{white}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Hi @Hello_world! I'm glad you like it.  Don't forget to accept the answer. I guess you can recover the dark border line from your image.