# Aperiodic tiling shapes draw in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need a grid made up of pieces that look like a hat in tikz. Here is the piece with four hats. Could you help? Can we use a tikzlibrary for tiling of this?

[image: aperiodic tiling]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-0]
\def\ra{1}
    \coordinate(O) at(0,0);
\coordinate(A1) at(0:\ra);
\coordinate(A2) at(60:\ra);
\coordinate(A3) at(120:\ra);
\path(A2)--(A1)--([turn]-60:\ra/2)coordinate(A01);
\draw[fill=yellow!6, thick](O)--(A01)--(A1)--(A2)--++(-\ra/2,0)--++(0,\ra)--([turn]60:\ra)--([turn]90:\ra/2)--([turn]60:\ra/2)--([turn]-90:\ra)--++(0,-\ra)coordinate(A3)--++(\ra/2,0)coordinate(A4)--([turn]-60:\ra/2)coordinate(A5)--cycle;

\draw[fill=gray!6, thick](O)--(A5)--(A4)--(A3)--++(-\ra/2,0)--([turn]60:\ra/2)coordinate(B1)--([turn]90:\ra)coordinate(B2) --++(0,-\ra)coordinate(B3)--++(\ra/2,0)coordinate(B4)--([turn]-60:\ra/2)coordinate(B5)--([turn]90:\ra)coordinate(B6)--++(0,\ra)coordinate(B7)--++(\ra/2,0)coordinate(B8)--(A01)--cycle;

\draw[fill=purple!6, thick](A01)--(B8)--(B7)--(B6)--(B5)--([turn]90:\ra/2)coordinate(D1)--++(\ra, 0)--([turn]60:\ra/2)--([turn]-90:\ra)--([turn]60:\ra)--([turn]90:\ra/2)--++(-\ra/2,0)--++(0,\ra)--(A01); 

\draw[fill=teal!6, thick](B5)--(B4)--(B3)--(B2)--(B1)--([turn]90:\ra/2)coordinate(C1)--([turn]60:\ra/2)--([turn]-90:\ra)--++(0,-\ra)--([turn]90:\ra/2)--([turn]-60:\ra/2)--([turn]90:\ra)--([turn]-60:\ra)--(D1)--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting that someone came with that very new shape and asks for tiling it here. You need to use a `pic` to tile those. But when it comes to place them correctly, it could be challenging. Good question.

Comment: https://github.com/loopspace/penrose/commit/5eecc1482a98a7591ca387af5fcd7122dd05e82c

Comment: This is the "einstein" -- recently reported in the press.  Eg  https://www.sciencenews.org/article/mathematicians-discovered-einstein-tile  The [paper announcing the discovery](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10798) has some details about how to create the tiling.

Comment: I'm not keen on the "ein stein" pun since mathematics has enough of a problem with naming things after the wrong person, but even using it then this tile is _an_ "ein stein", not _the_ "ein stein" so it is better to use a more specific name for it.

Comment: You say *Here is the piece with three hats* but I see four of them (four rotated copies of the same shape). Did I misunderstand what you mean by a *hat*?

Comment: OK, I have edited it.

Answer (score 19):

There is a TikZ library for this, originally designed for Penrose tilings from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440412/86, and I am in the process of updating it for the new tile.  Currently, I have the hat and turtle with a command for defining a `Tile(a,b)`, and the meta and super cluster tiles.  I'm now working on the substitution system for the super clusters, and wondering about the subclusters.

You can find the latest version [on github](https://github.com/loopspace/penrose), there's a [release](https://github.com/loopspace/penrose/releases/tag/v1.6) with all the necessary files in it, or for the bleeding edge version then the key file is `penrose_code.dtx`, download that and run `tex penrose_code.dtx` to generate the necessary files.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681708/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  tilings.polykite,
  calc,
}

\tikzset{
  hexagon/.pic={
    \path[pic actions] (1,0)
    foreach \k in {1,...,6} { -- (\k*60:1)}
    foreach \k in {1,...,6} {(0,0) -- (\k*60:1)}
    foreach \k in {1,...,6} {(0,0) -- (\k*60+30:{sqrt(3)/2})}
    ;
  },
  every tile/.style={draw}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every aperiodical hat/.style={
    draw,
    ultra thick
  },
]
\pic[draw=none,fill=gray!50] {aperiodical hat};
\pic[draw,gray] at (-1,0) {hexagon};
\pic[draw,gray] at (60:1) {hexagon};
\pic[draw,gray] at (-60:1) {hexagon};
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-a];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-b,align with=hat-a along 11 using 4];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-c,align with=hat-a along 26 using 7];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-d,align with=hat-a along 24 using 5];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-e,align with=hat-a along 13 using 2];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-f,align with=hat-a along 16 using 5];
\pic[red,flip tile,aperiodical hat,name=hat-g,align with=hat-a along 21 using 3];
\pic[aperiodical hat,name=hat-h,align with=hat-g back along 14 using 6];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above produces:

[image: Aperiodical hat using the penrose package]

Comment: Wow - I didn't even know TeX had such an expressive language. But do you really want to do the complex substitution stuff in that? Or does TikZ actually have a nicer language? Note relate discussions and implementations at [Add features for patch generation via substitution with customized visualization · Issue #3 · isohedral/hatvalidate](https://github.com/isohedral/hatvalidate/issues/3) - the Mathematica one is the best documented that I've seen. The hatviz code is pretty dense especially for a non-Javascript type like me....

Comment: @nealmcb I implemented the substitution code for Penrose tiles using the syntax of Lindenmayer systems so I already have the framework for it, just need to isolate the individual substitutions.  This is never going to be the most efficient code, though.

Comment: Very interesting. If your approach involves some sort of standard or clean syntax for describing einstein substitutions as an [L-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system), I wonder if that description could be used for implementations in other languages which have L-system libraries.

Comment: @nealmcb Presumably it would be helpful.  At the moment, I have the substitution system worked out for the super clusters (in a different language - I have two tiling programs that I work with).  That could be used to generate a polykite tiling, I suppose, by extracting the combinatorial data and then applying it to a polykite tiling.

Comment: Note also this fascinating alternative construction scheme, as an alternative to the original substitution approach: [Two algorithms for randomly generating aperiodic tilings](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/quasiblog/aperiodic-tilings/)

Comment: @nealmcb Thought you might be interested: https://github.com/loopspace/penrose/commit/90682ad9bd248401bc98c6bef2829f9a5726651f  Picture at https://twitter.com/mathforge/status/1656063048421978113?s=20

Answer (score 15):

First, let's draw the tile more precisely and also choose a corner as coordinate zero:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) coordinate (-i0)
    -- ++(60:1/2) coordinate (-i1)
    -- ++(120:1) coordinate (-i2)
    -- ++(180:1/2) coordinate (-i3)
    -- ++(90:{sin(60)}) coordinate (-i4)
    -- ++(150:{sin(60)}) coordinate (-i5)
    -- ++(240:1/2) coordinate (-i6)
    -- ++(300:1/2) coordinate (-i7)
    -- ++(210:{sin(60)}) coordinate (-i8)
    -- ++(270:{sin(60)}) coordinate (-i9) 
    -- ++(0:1/2) coordinate (-i10)
    -- ++(300:1/2) coordinate (-i11)
    -- ++(30:{sin(60)}) coordinate (-i12)
    -- cycle;

% adding the labels
\foreach \i in {0,...,12} {
    \pgfmathparse{int(\i == 3 || \i == 9 ? 1 : 0)}
    \draw[red] (-i\i) circle[radius=2pt];
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
        \node[below, red, font=\ttfamily\tiny] at (-i\i) {(-i\i)};
    \else
        \node[right, red, font=\ttfamily\tiny] at (-i\i) {(-i\i)};
    \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Having this, we can create a `pic` from it. Since we would like to mirror and  rotate this `pic` and also place it relative to others, we need to create it in a special way so that we first create the coordinates and only then draw the path having the possibility to shift and rotate the coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newif\ifaperiodicalhatmirrored
\tikzset{
    pics/aperiodical hat/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{
                aperiodical hat/.cd, 
                #1,
                coordinate transformation/.style={
                    rotate around={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/rotate around inner anchor}:(-inner anchor)},
                    shift={($(-outer anchor)-(-inner anchor)$)},
                }
            }
            \ifaperiodicalhatmirrored
                \path[xscale=-1]
            \else
                \path
            \fi
                (0,0) coordinate (-i0)
                -- ++(60:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i1)
                -- ++(120:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}}) coordinate (-i2)
                -- ++(180:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i3)
                -- ++(90:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}*sin(60)}) coordinate (-i4)
                -- ++(150:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}*sin(60)}) coordinate (-i5)
                -- ++(240:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i6)
                -- ++(300:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i7)
                -- ++(210:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}*sin(60)}) coordinate (-i8)
                -- ++(270:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}*sin(60)}) coordinate (-i9) 
                -- ++(0:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i10)
                -- ++(300:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}/2}) coordinate (-i11)
                -- ++(30:{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/base unit}*sin(60)}) coordinate (-i12)
                -- cycle;
            \coordinate (-inner anchor) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/inner anchor});
            \coordinate (-outer anchor) at (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/aperiodical hat/outer anchor});
            \path[pic actions]
                ([aperiodical hat/coordinate transformation]-i0) coordinate (-o0)
                    foreach \x in {1,...,12} { 
                        -- ([aperiodical hat/coordinate transformation]-i\x) coordinate (-o\x)
                    } -- cycle;
        }
    },
    aperiodical hat/base unit/.initial={1},
    aperiodical hat/inner anchor/.initial={0,0},
    aperiodical hat/outer anchor/.initial={0,0},
    aperiodical hat/rotate around inner anchor/.initial={0},
    aperiodical hat/mirrored/.is if={aperiodicalhatmirrored}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic[draw, fill=yellow!6] (tile1) {aperiodical hat};

\pic[draw, fill=black!6] (tile2) {aperiodical hat={inner anchor={-i5}, rotate around inner anchor=-60, mirrored}};

\pic[draw, fill=red!6] (tile3) {aperiodical hat={inner anchor={-i9}, rotate around inner anchor=240}};

\pic[draw, fill=green!6] (tile4) {aperiodical hat={inner anchor={-i2}, outer anchor={tile2-o10}}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The pic `aperiodical hat` takes the following options:

- `base unit`: factor to scale the tile.
- `inner anchor`: anchor of the current tile.
- `outer anchor`: anchor of another tile (or some coordinate) which the anchor specified with `inner anchor` should sit at.
- `rotate around inner anchor`: degrees the tile should be rotated around the coordinate specified by `inner anchor`.
- `mirrored`: if used, the tile is mirrored.

There are two sets of anchors in each `pic`. The first set is `-i0` to `-i12` and represents the corners of the tile before it is rotated and shifted (but after it has been mirrored). The second set is `-o0` to `-o12` and represents the corners of the tile after all transformations are applied. For `inner anchor` the first set (`-i0` to `-i12`) should typically be used, for `outer anchor` the second set (`-o0` to `-o12`) should be used.

Having this functionality, I assume it should be possible to create also larger tilings ...

Comment: What a beautiful tutorial! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Another `\pic` version. This one uses a hexagonal grid with coordinates to place the tiles. As we have an 'aperiodic tiling' we need to place the tiles by hand but the grid helps with that.

For example, trying to replicate part of [the first image here](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/mathematicians-discovered-einstein-tile?utm_source=Nature%20Briefing&utm_campaign=24e496a6a9-briefing-dy-20230324&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_c9dfd39373-24e496a6a9-42653487) the code could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset
{%
  tile1/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=blue!40!cyan},
  tile2/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=cyan!50},
  tile3/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=gray!30},
  tile4/.style={thick,draw=black,fill=white},
  pics/tile/.style={
    code={%
    \path[pic actions] (0,0)            --++ (330:{cos(30)})  --++ (60:0.5)  --++ (120:1)   -|++
                       (-0.5,{cos(30)}) --++ (150:{cos(30)})  --++ (240:0.5) --++ (300:0.5) --++
                       (210:{cos(30)})  |-++ (0.5,{-cos(30)}) --++ (300:0.5) -- cycle;
    % to show the hexagons, remove it or comment it if you want
    \draw[very thin,gray] (30:{cos(30)}) -- (0,0) -- (150:{2*cos(30)})
                     (0,0) -- (90:{cos(30)}) --++ (180:0.5) --++ (120:0.5) --++ (30:{cos(30)})
                     (-1,0) --++ (60:1);
    }}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% grid and clip
\foreach\i in {0,...,9} \foreach[count=\j]\jj in {A,...,H} 
  \coordinate (\jj\i) at ({\j+0.5*mod(\i,2)},{\i*cos(30)});
\clip[draw] ($(A1)+(-0.2,0.2)$) rectangle ($(G8)+(0.2,-0.2)$);
% tiles
\pic[tile2]                      at (B1) {tile};
\pic[tile2,rotate=240]           at (D2) {tile};
\pic[tile4,rotate=120]           at (G2) {tile};
\pic[tile1,rotate=300,xscale=-1] at (B3) {tile};
\pic[tile3,rotate=300]           at (E3) {tile};
\pic[tile2,rotate=60]            at (H3) {tile};
\pic[tile4,rotate=120]           at (A4) {tile};
\pic[tile2]                      at (D4) {tile};
\pic[tile4,rotate=60]            at (B5) {tile};
\pic[tile3]                      at (E5) {tile};
\pic[tile4,rotate=180]           at (G6) {tile};
\pic[tile3,rotate=240]           at (B7) {tile};
\pic[tile3,rotate=180]           at (A8) {tile};
\pic[tile2,rotate=120]           at (G8) {tile};
\pic[tile4,rotate=120]           at (E9) {tile};
% to show the grid
%\foreach\i in {0,...,9} \foreach[count=\j]\jj in {A,...,H} 
%  \fill (\jj\i) node[right] {\footnotesize$\jj\i$} circle (0.4mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And produces:
[image]

**Update:** A 'map' to help with placing the tiles could be
[image]

Comment: The grid idea for placement simplifies things a bit lot indeed! I have to admit that I first did not realize that these tiles could be placed on a grid at all.

Comment: @JasperHabicht, my first approach was similar to yours, but the image in my link gave the idea for the grid

Comment: Can you make it a greater grid?

Comment: @Epa, you only need to modify the line `\foreach\i in {0,...,9} \foreach[count=\j]\jj in {A,...,H}`. Change 9 and H for any other number or letter.

Comment: @Epa If you want larger tiles, you can always scale things using `x=2cm, y=2cm` (or whatever dimension you like) as option to the `tikzpicture`.

Comment: No, I want the greater number of hats within the same rectangular clip.

Comment: Then see @JasperHabicht comment: change the size of the `\pic`. Or you can scale the `tikzpicture`, say `scale=0.5`, and change the limits in the loops as I said in my previous comment. But, of course, if you want more tiles you need to draw them

Comment: @Juan Castano: I have modified \foreach ... yet the hard part is to put each at the right angle. I need a tesselation of approximately 100 hats, with about 9 in each row.

Comment: @Epa, yep, that's the hard part. But the angles are multiples of 60. When you have enough tiles placed (I think there are enough in my example) then the next tile will have the same angle that some of the already drawn. Look for one that looks the same

Comment: Yes, I tried all the multiples from 0 to 360 for some particular locations. Not easy.

Comment: Juan, can you help to put more than 120 hats in form? I tried but I failed.

Comment: @Epa, see my update

Comment: Not just the right angle and the right scale, the right node also matters, not to mention the fact that there are more than one possible options for some particular locations. A lot of trials and errors.  For instance, I put in three of the following, and the next around  C9 is not possible.

 \pic[tile4,rotate=120]           at (H1) {tile};
  \pic[tile4,rotate=120, xscale=-1]           at (B9) {tile};
   \pic[tile4,rotate=180, xscale=1]           at (B11) {tile};